# Ionic VirtualScroll show empty list when giving array of objects as dummy data

Tags: ionic3

I am new to ionic. I want to use the virtual scroll to display a list of the card in my app. I wonder how virtual list would accept the array of object. I will implements JSON in the future. just want to make the frame first.

```
<ion-list [virtualScroll]='vouchers' [approxItemHeight]="'132px'">

  <ion-card *virtualItem='let voucher' class='restaurantCard'>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-3>
        <ion-img [src]='voucher.image'></ion-img>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-8>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col>{{voucher.restaurantName}}</ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-2>[{{voucher.areaAvailable}}]</ion-col>
          <ion-col col-10>{{voucher.voucherName}}</ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col>{{voucher.currency}}</ion-col>
          <ion-col>{{voucher.newPrice}}</ion-col>
          <ion-col>{{voucher.currency}}{{voucher.basePrice}}</ion-col>
          <ion-col>
            <ion-row>
              <ion-col>{{voucher.quantitySold}} Sold</ion-col>
            </ion-row>
            <ion-row>
              <ion-col>{{voucher.restaurantArea}}</ion-col>
            </ion-row>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-card>

</ion-list>
```

the dummy data I try to send to it.

```
  public vouchers: any = [
    {
      image: '../../assets/imgs/vilaggio.jpeg',
      restaurantName: 'Vilaggio Restaurant',
      areaAvailable: 'JB',
      voucherName: 'RM 50 Voucher (1 pcs)',
      currency: 'RM',
      newPrice: 30,
      basePrice: 50,
      quantitySold: 118,
      restaurantArea: 'Johor Bahru'
    },
    {
      image: '../../assets/imgs/pahpai.jpeg',
      restaurantName: 'Pahpai Steak House',
      areaAvailable: 'ALL',
      voucherName: 'Valuable Steak selector',
      currency: 'RM',
      newPrice: 20,
      basePrice: 25,
      quantitySold: 32,
      restaurantArea: 'Sutera Mall'
    }
  ]
```

The list will show if I just use *ngFor to loop through the array of objects. but when using virtual scroll. I got a empty list (they show nothing) :(

Comment: I cannot see any issue in your code. see https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ebmshi?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort to show it in stackblitz! hmm but I tried the code you use in stackblitz. still no luck. I even tried just writing the <ion-list> and <ion-card> which contain the virtualscroll property. still not showing anything. I wonder why...(still finding). I will provide more information when I come back to that later :)!